# Can not read file from libpgm package

Tags: python, bayesian-networks

I installed libpgm for my jupyter notebook by

pip install libpgm

and then ran several imports as follow

```
import sys
import json
import libpgm
from libpgm.nodedata import NodeData
from libpgm.graphskeleton import GraphSkeleton
from libpgm.hybayesiannetwork import HyBayesianNetwork
```

I got an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\19413\conda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3343, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-7-80536a116c64>", line 4, in <module>
    from libpgm.nodedata import NodeData

  File "C:\Users\19413\conda\lib\site-packages\libpgm\nodedata.py", line 91
    print "Error: NodeData did not recognize input file format."
          ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("Error: NodeData did not recognize input file format.")?
```

Does anyone know what caused the error?

Thanks very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Well, the last line of your error report says exactly what caused the error:

```
Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("Error: NodeData did not recognize input file format.")?
```

Unlike Python 2, Python 3 requires all print statements to be enclosed in parentheses. I'm not familiar with the `libpgm` library but it seems to me that this [has been fixed five years ago](https://github.com/CyberPoint/libpgm/blob/be32202d28f53cf3761a2e31ea8ffcdc3e383789/build/lib/libpgm/nodedata.py#L91). Make sure that you use the newest version of this library or run your code with Python 2 instead.

Comment: Thanks Kaspar. I updated the installation with this pip install -U libpgm
Requirement already up-to-date: libpgm in c:\users\19413\conda\lib\site-packages (1.3)
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages. but still saw the error